# SAP Inbound IDoc Fields and Outbound IDoc Fields Mapping Before Outbound IDoc Trigger

Tags: abap, sap-erp, idoc, sap-data-services

BODS sends data to SAP System and we don't want to change pointers to trigger Outbound IDoc.

Now challenge is to map BODS Segment Fields to SAP IDoc Fields before trigger Outbound IDoc manually using ABAP Code.

Ex:

BODS Field `MATERIAL` should be mapped to `MATMAS`-`MATNR`, and there are many fields.

I am aware of FM `MASTER_IDOC_DISTRIBUTE` and method `start_outbound` of class `cl_drf_outbound`. But where to get the mapping is the challenge.

Any idea would be helpful.

Thank you,
Priyanka

Comment: The flow is not very clear. Are you saying that you want to run some ABAP code in BODS before it triggers the Outbound IDoc? Are you talking about reusing a mapping defined in BODS? Is there a third system implied? (BODS -> SAP ERP -> another one?)

Comment: This sentence lost me
'Now challenge is to map BODS Segment Fields to SAP IDoc Fields before trigger Outbound IDoc manually using ABAP Code.'

how is that even possible ? There is something missing in the explanation.
Given SAP BODS isnt ABAP.  Or at least it wasnt last time I checked.